# PhpStorm indexing when clicking Ctrl+Space

Tags: phpstorm

Everytime I click <kbd>Ctrl + Space</kbd> to auto complete variables etc. my PhpStorm doesn't show any completion and just indexes my project. I have looked at my keybind's and <kbd>Ctrl + Space</kbd> is assigned to `Code -> Completion -> Basic`

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Same binding here. Think that's correct mate, I **do** get autocompletion. As a work-around and pain-in-the-ass-type of thing to do, you might want to reinstall PhpStorm **without** importing settings.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Nukeface, I have just fixed it by reinstalling like you said, I did import my settings from my repo and its still works. Must be some sort of bug in PhpStorm which shows/uses incorrect binds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by uninstalling PhpStorm and deleting my `.PhpStorm2017.3` directory in `C:\Users\<username>` then reinstalling the latest version.

I imported my settings from my repo after the install and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Next time try `File | Invalidate Caches...` and restart IDE first -- might be enough (solves in most of such cases where you have completion/navigation issues).

Comment: @LazyOne you should add this comment as an answer, the is the mot correct solution, uninstall is not an option for me.